# Leaflet MarkerCluster Spiderfy dynamic line color

Tags: leaflet

I'm using the LeafLet MarkerCluster plugin ( https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster )

Does anyone know if it is possible to color the MarkerCluster Spiderfy line color dynamically?

For example, I can set other things dynamically like this:

```
            markersFeatureLayer.eachLayer(function(layer) {
                layer.feature.properties.line = 'green';
                    layer.setIcon(L.MyMarkers.icon({
                        icon: layer.feature.properties.myData.icon,
                        markerColor: layer.feature.properties['icon-color'],
                        iconColor: '#FFFFFF'
                      }));
              mapClusterLayer.addLayer(layer);
            });
```

Or this

```
     mapClusterLayer = new L.MarkerClusterGroup({
        maxClusterRadius: 2,   
        spiderfyDistanceMultiplier: 3,
        removeOutsideVisibleBounds: false,
            iconCreateFunction: function(cluster) {
              return new L.DivIcon({
                iconSize: [30, 30],
                html: '<div style="text-align:center;color:#fff;background:' +
                'green' + '">' + cluster.getChildCount() + '</div>',
              });
            }        
          });
```

I want each spider line to be equal to markerColor. So each will have a unique color.

Any ideas?

Comment: Readme says `spiderLegPolylineOptions: Allows you to specify PolylineOptions to style spider legs. By default, they are { weight: 1.5, color: '#222' }.` If that's what you're looking for you should be able to modify this with something like `var markers = new L.MarkerClusterGroup({ spiderLegPolylineOptions: {color: pink} });`

Comment: Sorry, I was not specific enough. I realize I can set the spider line color, but I need to do it dynamically so that each leg has a unique color.

I've updated the original post.

Comment: spiderlegpolylineoption not working please take a look  http://jsfiddle.net/dbanka/wSytj/98/